# Add arbitrary route prefix to all attribute routes in webapi 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

This was kind of asked at [Web Api 2 global route prefix for route attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070559/web-api-2-global-route-prefix-for-route-attributes).

I'm using attribute routing and class level route prefixes already. However, from a configuration of some sort (could be code) I would like to add another prefix to all the attribute routes. I do not want to create custom route attributes to use throughout my code base, just the built in ones.

Is this possible?

Simply put, I would like to take my routes
/a/1/b/2
and
/x/3/y/2/z/1
and turn them in to (although it doesn't necessarily need to be a /api prefix)
/api/1/b/2
and
/api/x/3/y/2/z/1

Comment: One way to do this would be to create a custom route handler (search IRouteHandler)

Comment: A bit more overhead, but another option would be configuration in your server. Assuming IIS, you could use a virtual directory/application, or even modify routes using something like nginx. Not sure if this is an option but mentioning it for completeness sake.

Comment: I'll have to take a look at using a custom route handler. Never looked into it before. If it can be used as a sort of cross-cutting concern by just replacing or extending an existing one in the request pipeline then that could be a pretty elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

You could create an abstract base controller class that all other controllers inherit from and apply the `RoutePrefix` attribute to that. For example:

```
[RoutePrefix("/api")
public abstract class BaseController : ApiController
{
}
```

And then my normal controllers would look like this:

```
public class ValuesController : BaseController
{
    [Route("/get/value")]
    public string GetValue()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

A secondary option is to use a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) that will transparently route all incoming requests to the correct URL. You could set the proxy up with a rewrite rule such as "any request that matches `/api/*`, redirect to `internalserver/*`". You can use [ARR](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) for IIS to do this and it is free. I have used it in the past and it works very well for situations like this.

Comment: That's also something I'd like to avoid. I would like my code base to be unaware of the fact that it's being routed paths with a prefix.

Comment: If you want it to be completely outside your app then you could use a reverse proxy server to rewrite incoming requests.

Comment: For example, using [ARR](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) you can get IIS to rewrite `/api/*` to just `/*` and your app won't even know about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also read the Routes of the default HttpConfiguration and just create a new HttpConfiguration with the only difference that you apply a prefix to the routeTemplate. At the end you use this HttpConfiguration then.

Theoretically you could also create a new WebApi Startup class and your old one provides it's HttpConfiguration as a property in case you want to change routes in a seperate web project.

Something like:

```
HttpConfiguration oldCofiguration = OtherWebService.Startup.Config;
HttpConfiguration newCofiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
foreach(var oldRoute in oldCofiguration.Routes){
    newCofigurationRoutes.MapHttpRoute(
            "YourRouteName",
            "yourPrefix" + oldRoute .routeTemplate ,
            new
            {
                controller = oldRoute.Controller
            },
            null,
            null
            );
}
```

You need to adapt the code to your needs. (Sorry the code is untested, as I have no access to IDE just now)